# A Query on lists in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and have a basic query. See the below code, where I wanted to print the index of array on the browser console when any person's name get clicked.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Para from './Para/Para';


class App extends Component {

state = {
  persons : ['Max', 'Nick', 'Peter']
}

clickHandler= (index) =>{
  console.log(`CLICKED ${index}`);
}


  render() {

    var members = [];
    this.state.persons.forEach((element,index)=>{
      members.push(<Para clicked= {this.clickHandler.bind(this,index)} name={element} key={element}></Para>);
    })

    return (
     <div>
      {members}
     </div>
    );

  }
}
export default App;
```

**Functional Component - Para.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const para = (props) =>{
   return( <p onClick = {props.clicked}>{props.name}</p>)
}

export default para;
```

I am receiving output as expected. My query here is that how react is able to find the index of the person's name in array when get clicked? Because when page gets loaded, all the components got rendered and when the element (person's name) get's clicked, does react re-render this functional component to find the index..? What is actually happening behind the scenes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: React is not finding the index, you are giving an index `{this.clickHandler.bind(this,index)` check this you are passing it.

Comment: @Justcode Thank you for your comment. So, the binding has to happen upon click right. So, how does react know the index value as the component was already been rendered on page load.

Comment: I think react does nothing in this, it just passing the index which you passed when binding it. every loop item is treated as separate element.

Comment: Just a tip, it's good practice not to add event handlers to non-interactive elements. If this was an interactive element you could get the value from `event.target.value`. [Read here](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-noninteractive-element-interactions.md) for what I mean.

Comment: So, react doesn't re-render the functional component to bind the index. How can that instantaneously happen? I mean index doesn't get bind on page load, but does only when it get's clicked. I am still confused how react knows the index of element at the time it gets clicked.

Comment: the expression in `clicked={expression}` is executed immediately == the `index` is bound during each render, compare `clicked={console.log('before clicked')}` vs `clicked={() => console.log('after clicked')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for explanation how it works, `this.clickHandler.bind(this,index)` returns a [partially applied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) function - logically equivalent to `(...args) => clickHandler(index, ...args)`

---

FWIW: `onClick` built-in prop for event handlers are always called with `event` as the first argument, so an idiomatic way how to pass other arguments is to use a factory / closure variable, e.g.:

```
makeClickHandler = (index) => (event) => { console.log(`CLICKED ${index}`) }
...<Para clicked={makeClickHandler(index)}...
```

this way it's explicit that you want to ignore the `event` argument of the `clickHandler` function (which is returned as an anonymous function by `makeClickHandler()`)

Answer (score 1):

You loop through your array, and on every element you have an access to the index of it.
(That's only JS feature, not React, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

So you "assign" a function with a specific argument(index) as a prop.
You're basically saying "This unique element, when clicked, runs `clickHandler(1)`". Another one "runs `clickHandler(2)`" etc.

And when you assigned multiple divs to the `members`, you render it. In your code nothing gets updated, because the state stays the same.